# Additional styles added to a style sheet cause problems

Tags: html, css

I have created a website that worked fine before.

Now I added some code to my style.css.

This was my original style.css:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,300italic,400italic');
@import url('font-awesome.min.css');

/*
    Astral by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
*/


/*********************************************************************************/
/* Basic                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/

    body
    {
        background-image:           url('images/overlay.png'),      url('images/bg.jpg');
        background-repeat:          repeat,                         no-repeat;
        background-size:            auto,                           100% 100%;
    }

        body.is-loading *
        {
            -moz-transition: none !important;
            -webkit-transition: none !important;
            -o-transition: none !important;
            -ms-transition: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
            -moz-animation: none !important;
            -webkit-animation: none !important;
            -o-animation: none !important;
            -ms-animation: none !important;
            animation: none !important;
        }

    body,input,textarea,select
    {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: SVG; /*#777777;*/
    }

    strong, b
    {
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #363636;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4,h5, h6
    {
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #363636;
    }

    blockquote
    {
        border-left: solid 0.5em #ddd;
        padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    em, i
    {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    hr
    {
        border: 0;
        border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
        padding: 1.5em 0 0 0;
        margin: 1.75em 0 0 0;
    }

    sub
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0.5em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    sup
    {
        position: relative;
        top: -0.5em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    br.clear
    {
        clear: both;
    }

    p, ul, ol, dl, table, blockquote, form
    {
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    /* Table */

        table
        {
            width: 100%;
        }

            table.default
            {
            }

                table.default tbody tr
                {
                    border-bottom: solid 1px #f4f4f4;
                }

                table.default td
                {
                    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
                }

                table.default th
                {
                    text-align: left;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
                }

                table.default thead
                {
                    border-bottom: solid 2px #f4f4f4;
                }

    /* Form */

        form
        {
        }

            form label
            {
                display: block;
                font-weight: 400;
                color: #363636;
                margin: 0 0 1em 0;
            }

            form input[type="text"],
            form input[type="email"],
            form input[type="password"],
            form select,
            form textarea
            {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                border: 0;
                background: #FFFFFF;
                padding: 0.75em;
                width: 100%;
                -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
                transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            }

            form input[type="text"],
            form input[type="email"],
            form input[type="password"],
            form select
            {
                line-height: 1.35em;
            }

            form input[type="text"]:focus,
            form input[type="email"]:focus,
            form input[type="password"]:focus,
            form select:focus,
            form textarea:focus
            {
                background: #f8f8f8;
            }

            form ::-webkit-input-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }

            form :-moz-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }

            form ::-moz-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }

            form :-ms-input-placeholder
            {
                color: #999;
            }       

    /* Section/Article */

        section,
        article
        {
            margin-bottom: 3em;
        }

            section > :last-child,
            article > :last-child
            {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

            section:last-child,
            article:last-child
            {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

        header
        {
        }

            header > p
            {
                color: #aaa;
            }

    /* Image */



    .codeboxspace
    {

    min-width:1000px;
    max-width:1400px;
    width:95%;
    display:none;
    }
    #codebox
          {
          font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace; 
          font-size: 90%;
          line-height: 140%;
          white-space: pre;
          white-space: pre-wrap;
          white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
          white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
          background: #E0E0E0;
          display: block;
          padding: 0.5em 1em;
          border: 1px solid #bebab0;
          text-align:left;
          color:black;
          height : 100%;
          width:920px;
         } 

        .image
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }


            .image img
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .image.fit
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .image.featured
            {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            }

            .image.left
            {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
            }

            .image.centered
            {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            }

                .image.centered img
                {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    width: auto;
                }

    /* Button */    

        input[type="button"],
        input[type="submit"],
        input[type="reset"],
        .button
        {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #222222;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: 0;
            -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
        }

            input[type="button"]:hover,
            input[type="submit"]:hover,
            input[type="reset"]:hover,
            .button:hover
            {
                background-color: #333333;
            }

            input[type="button"]:active,
            input[type="submit"]:active,
            input[type="reset"]:active,
            .button:active
            {
                background-color: #444444;
            }

            input[type="button"].alt,
            input[type="submit"].alt,
            input[type="reset"].alt,
            .button.alt
            {
                background-color: #777777;
            }

                input[type="button"].alt:hover,
                input[type="submit"].alt:hover,
                input[type="reset"].alt:hover,
                .button.alt:hover
                {
                    background-color: #888888;
                }

                input[type="button"].alt:active,
                input[type="submit"].alt:active,
                input[type="reset"].alt:active,
                .button.alt:active
                {
                    background-color: #999999;
                }

    /* List */

        ul.default
        {
            list-style: disc;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }

            ul.default li
            {
                padding-left: 0.5em;
            }

        ul.actions
        {
        }

            ul.actions li
            {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: 0.5em;
            }

                ul.actions li:first-child
                {
                    margin-left: 0;
                }

        ol.default
        {
            list-style: decimal;
            padding-left: 1.25em;
        }

            ol.default li
            {
                padding-left: 0.25em;
            }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Icons                                                                         */
/*********************************************************************************/

    .icon {
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .icon:before {
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: none !important;
        }

        .icon > .label {
            display: none;
        }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Nav                                                                           */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #nav
    {
    }

        #nav a
        {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 1em;
            height: 1em;
            line-height: 0.9em;
        }

            #nav a.icon:before
            {
                padding-right: 0;
            }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Panels                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #main
    {
        position: relative;

        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .panel
    {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* Me */

        #me
        {
        }

            #me .pic
            {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
            }

                #me .pic:before
                {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    background: url('images/overlay.png');
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    z-index: 1;
                }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Footer                                                                        */
/*********************************************************************************/

    #footer
    {
        color: #ccc;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.45);
    }

        #footer a
        {
            color: #ddd;
            color: rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
            -moz-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: color .25s ease-in-out;
        }

        #footer a:hover
        {
            color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
        }

        #footer .copyright
        {
        }

            #footer .copyright li
            {
                display: inline-block;
            }

                #footer .copyright li:before
                {
                    display: inline;
                    content: '\2022';
                    opacity: 0.5;
                    padding: 0 0.75em 0 0.75em;
                }

                #footer .copyright li:first-child:before
                {
                    display: none;
                }



#skill { 
    list-style: none;
    font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    width: 296px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

#skill li { 
    margin-bottom:50px; 
    background:#e9e5e2;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e1ddd9), to(#e9e5e2));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e1ddd9, #e9e5e2);  
    height:20px; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;   
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;    
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #bebbb9 inset, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;     
}

#skill li h3 { 
    position:relative; 
    top:-25px;
}

.bar { 
    height:18px; 
    margin:1px 2px;  
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #fcfcfc inset, 0 1px 0 #bebbb9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #fcfcfc inset, 0 1px 0 #bebbb9;    
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #fcfcfc inset, 0 1px 0 #bebbb9;       
}

.unity {
    width:80%; 
    -moz-animation:unity 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation:unity 2s ease-out;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FF0000), to(#FF0000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FF0000, #FF0000);
}

.html-css {
    width:50%;
    -moz-animation:html-css 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation:html-css 2s ease-out;
    background-color: #FF8000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FF8000), to(#FF8000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FF8000, #FF8000);
}

.testing {
    width:20%;
    -moz-animation:testing 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation:testing 2s ease-out;
    background-color: #192AFF;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#192AFF), to(#192AFF));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #192AFF, #192AFF);
}

@-moz-keyframes unity       {0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes html-css    { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes testing         { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;}  }

@-webkit-keyframes unity       { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:80%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes html-css        { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:50%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes testing       { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:20%;}  }
```

And my webpage looks like this when I use the code above and it also needs to look like this:

http://i61.tinypic.com/2gxl76f.png

But then I added this code to the bottom of the style.css file:

```
div.container {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 675px;
}
div.image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
span.title {
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.9);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
div.image.revealUpFull span {
    height: 141px;
    width: 150px;
    bottom: -120px;
    display: block;
}
div.image.revealUpFull span a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
div.image.revealUpFull:hover img {
    top: -150px;
}
div.image.revealUpFull:hover span {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

But then it all looks like this, which is not how it should be:

http://i61.tinypic.com/2drwbht.png

Please help me figure out how to get the page displaying as it should.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've formatted your question, removed a number of spelling and grammar errors, and changed your title to be a bit more descriptive. It would be very helpful if you could detail exactly what problems you are seeing. Trying to switch between two images is time consuming for answerers. It might also help you if you can reduce the amount of code by finding what code is causing the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: take away the code you added...then add back one chunk at a time until what you don't want to happen happens.